# Fetch Data from database and project it on a Datatable using django/ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, datatable

I just recently learned Django/ajax/datatables. I can project my data using a {%for%} loop and im trying to do the same thing with ajax calls.

**My view:**

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

def getfromServer(request):
    if is_ajax(request=request) and request.method == "GET":
        books= Book.objects.all()
        bookserial = serializers.serialize('json', books)
        return JsonResponse(bookserial, safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({'message':'Wrong validation'})
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="books" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Book</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Date Publishedd</th>
                <th>Copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
     </table>
</div>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#books').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype : 'json',
                    url: 'views/getfromServer',
                },
                columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'author' },
            { data: 'genre' },
            { data: 'pub_date' },
            { data: 'copies' },
           ]
            });
</script>
```

Im pretty sure it kinda works this way but i just cant figure it out .

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery DataTable is a powerful and smart HTML table enhancing plugin provided by jQuery JavaScript library`

So it doesn't make sense to put an ajax request inside the `.DataTable()` method
You have to make the ajax request first:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype : 'json',
    url: 'views/getfromServer',
    success: function (result) { // result is the response you get from the server if successful
        // Use the data in result to write the values to your html table respectively here
    }
    error: function (err) {
        // handle error
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

thats what I came up with but still doesnt seem to do the trick all i get is an empty table .

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        datatype : 'json',
        url: "views/getfromServer", // "{% url 'index' %}"
        success: function (response) {
            var instant = JSON.parse(response[books]);
            
            for book in books {
                var fields= instant[book]["fields"];
                $("#books tbody").prepend(
                    `<tr>
                        <td>${fields["name"]||""}</td>
                        <td>${fields["author"]||""}</td>
                        <td>${fields["genre"]||""}</td>
                        <td>${fields["pub_date"]||""}</td>
                        <td>${fields["copies"]||""}</td>
                    </tr>`
                )
            }

        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
        }
    
    })
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#books').DataTable();
```

Comment: uhh I think it should be `var instant = JSON.parse(response)[books];`
you have to parse it before being able to access it